# i created registration form on reactjs, my registration form seems working but i didn't get any email verification

Tags: javascript, reactjs

just like the title said i created registration form using react js, at first it's working when finish fill the form it link to another page. But the problem is after user fill all the form it suppose to automatically send email verification and i didn't get any email verification. can anyone help me with this problem, i still new using react jS. any help would be appreciated...

this is my code if anyone wondering:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';

  import {Redirect, Link, router } from 'react-router-dom'; 

  import './SignUp.css';

  import axios from 'axios';

  export default class Login extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {

  window.scrollTo(0, 0)

  }

    constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state={

    company: '',

    province: '',

    city: '',

    website: '',

    address: '',

    contact:'',

    password:'',

    email:'',    

    errors: {}

    }


    this.handleChangeCompany = this.handleChangeCompany.bind(this);

    this.handleChangeWebsite = this.handleChangeWebsite.bind(this);

    this.handleChangeProvince = this.handleChangeProvince.bind(this);

    this.handleChangeCity= this.handleChangeCity.bind(this);

    this.handleChangeAddress = this.handleChangeAddress.bind(this);

    this.handleChangeMobile = this.handleChangeMobile.bind(this);

    this.handleChangeEmail = this.handleChangeEmail.bind(this);

    this.handleChangePassword = this.handleChangePassword.bind(this);

    this.submituserRegistrationForm = this.submituserRegistrationForm.bind(this);

    }

    handleChangeWebsite(e) {

    this.setState({website:e.target.value});

    }

    handleChangeProvince(e) {

    this.setState({province:e.target.value});

    }

    handleChangeCity(e) {

    this.setState({city:e.target.value});

    }

    handleChangeCompany(e) {

    this.setState({company:e.target.value});

    }

    handleChangeAddress(e) {

    this.setState({address:e.target.value});

    }

    handleChangeEmail(e) {

    this.setState({email:e.target.value});

    }

    handleChangeMobile(e) {

    this.setState({contact:e.target.value});

    }

    handleChangePassword(e) {

    this.setState({password:e.target.value});

    }


  submituserRegistrationForm(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

  if (this.validateForm()) {

    var apiBaseUrl = "http://THIS_IS_MY_API_:3000";

    var data={

    "query":"mutation{ createProfile( profileInput :{company: \""+this.state.company+"\", address: \""+this.state.address+"\", email: \""+this.state.email+"\", contact: \""+this.state.contact+"\", province: \""+this.state.province+"\", city: \""+this.state.city+"\", website: \"\", operational: 24, password: \""+this.state.password+"\"}){  _id company address city province email contact website logo createdAt updatedAt  } }"

    }

    /*console.log(data);*/

    var headers = {

      'Content-Type': 'application/json',



    }


    axios.post(apiBaseUrl, data, {headers: headers}).then(function (response) {

      if(response.data.data){

      console.log(response.data.data);

      localStorage.setItem("u_code", encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(response.data.data)));

      localStorage.setItem('is_done', true);

      window.location.href = "/login";

      console.log("Sign Up successfull");

    }else{

      alert(response.data.message);

    }

    }).catch(function (error) {

      console.log(error);

    });

   }

  }

    validateForm() {

      let errors = {};

      let formIsValid = true;


  return formIsValid;

  }

  render() {
    return (
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row no-gutter">
              <div className="d-none d-md-flex col-md-4 col-lg-6 bg-image" />
              <div className="col-md-8 col-lg-6">
                <div className="login d-flex align-items-center py-5">
                  <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-md-9 col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                        <h3 className="login-heading mb-4">Sign Up Now!</h3>
                        <form method="post" name="userRegistrationForm" onSubmit= {this.submituserRegistrationForm}>
                        <br></br>
                            <h5 className="login-heading mb-4"><u>Company</u></h5>
                          <div className="form-label-group">
                            <input name="company" value={this.state.company} onChange={this.handleChangeCompany} id="company" className="form-control" placeholder="Company" required autofocus />
                            <label htmlFor="company">Company</label>
                          </div>
                          <br></br>
                          <h5 className="login-heading mb-4"><u>City</u></h5>
                          <div className="form-label-group">
                            <input name="City" value={this.state.city} onChange={this.handleChangeCity} className="form-control" placeholder="City" required autofocus />
                            <label>City</label>
                          </div>
                          <br></br>

                          <h5 className="login-heading mb-4"><u>Address</u></h5>
                          <div className="form-label-group">
                            <input name="address" value={this.state.address} onChange={this.handleChangeAddress} className="form-control" placeholder="Address" required autofocus />
                            <label>Address</label>
                          </div>
                          <br></br>

                          <h5 className="login-heading mb-4"><u>Province</u></h5>
                          <div className="form-label-group">
                            <input name="Province" value={this.state.province} onChange={this.handleChangeProvince} className="form-control" placeholder="Province" required autofocus />
                            <label >Province</label>
                          </div>
                          <br></br>

                          <h5 className="login-heading mb-4"><u>Email Address</u></h5>
                          <div className="form-label-group">
                            <input name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChangeEmail} className="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus />
                            <label>Email</label>
                          </div>
                          <br></br>

                          <h5 className="login-heading mb-4"><u>Contact</u></h5>
                          <div className="form-label-group">
                            <input name="contact" value={this.state.contact} onChange={this.handleChangeMobile} className="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number" required autofocus />
                            <label>Contact</label>
                          </div>
                          <br></br>

                          <h5 className="login-heading mb-4"><u>Password</u></h5>
                          <div className="form-label-group">
                            <input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChangePassword} name="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                            <label htmlFor="inputPassword">Password</label>
                          </div>
                          <br></br>
                          <button value="Login" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-login text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-2" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                          </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the e-mail sending method? In your code, there is only a post to an API. Is the e-mail sending method on your API?

Comment: @silentw also when i fill all the form, i tried to login using my email and its not working. I always get email and password error like the server not recognize the my email and password i just input

Comment: @silentw my api is include email sending method. so i need email sending method in my code? if so how to use it ? –

Comment: You have to generate and send an e-mail on your API. What have you tried?

Comment: @silentw as far as i know API will be automatically send an email verification. if you successfully fill registration form the API will be send email verification to your email and if you receive email verification and not verify yet in postman it say error that email not yet verify. the problem is my email not recognize and it said my email does not exist. i still stuck with it i can't do anything yet

Comment: i still tried to edit my request in data section just in case i got typo or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's seems nothing wrong with the code it just i put Json web token in the wrong place.
the correct one is like this :

```
const getJWT = () => {
      return localStorage.getItem('token');
    };

const jwt = getJWT();
    if (!jwt){
      window.location.href = "/";
    };
```

instead of this, it created another token and thats why the server did not recognize because of unrecognized token :

```
          localStorage.setItem("u_code", encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(response.data.data)));

          localStorage.setItem('is_done', true);
```

in the header i just put jwt like this :

```
'Authorization' : 'Tesla '+jwt+''
```

Comment: also thanks for @silentw for answering my first post in stackoverflow :)